# How to retrieve a single cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table/excel sheet with below info:

```
Col A  Col B Col C
1         3   ABC
              CBA

2         4   TRA
              DEP
```

How do I retrieve just first cell from Col C for every 1 and 2 in Col A

Results should be displayed like below

```
Col A  Col B Col C Col D
1         3   ABC   ABC
              CBA

2         4   TRA   TRA
              DEP

3         5   TEA   TEA
              DEP
```

Comment: or even better, use a site like https://senseful.github.io/text-table/ to post an ascii table

Comment: your expected result is confusing. The first cell of Column C returns `ABC`, so based on your requirement **retrieve just first cell from Col C for every 1 and 2 in Col A** the corresponding value for `2` in Column D should be `ABC` but not `TRA`. And why is there `TEA` shown in Column D? What is the logic behind?

Answer (score 0):

In Cell D1 place the following and copy down:

```
=IF(A1<>"",C1,"")
```

The above will display the value in Column C provided the corresponding value in A is not blank.  If there was the possibility of TEXT being in Column A and you only want column C when its a number in column A you could go with the following.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(A1),C1,"")
```